# Adding a wildcard to Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 project, I have a route like this (via rake routes) :

```
user_articles_path   GET     /users/:user_id/articles(.:format)  articles#index
```

This works beautifully so that `/users/1/articles` shows user 1's articles.

What's the simplest way to get all articles from all users?

Something like `/users/*/articles` or `/users/all/articles` would be sweet.

Here's the Articlescontroller index method:

```
  def index
    @articles = if params[:user_id]
      user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      user.articles.where('content like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
    else
      current_user.articles.where('content like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
    end
  end
```

I show articles based on a user/id and then if a user is logged in (via Twitter) I show them their articles.

**Update**

Not sure if this is too hacky, but here's my current index method. It works like I want, but it could probably be simplified:

```
  def index
    if current_user
      if params[:user_id]
        user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @articles = user.articles.where('content like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
      else
        @articles = current_user.articles.where('content like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
      end
    else
      @articles = Article.all.where('content like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
    end
```

end

Articles are there for logged in and logged out users with easy routing to show a specific user's articles. Suggestions for cleaning it are welcome.

Comment: There's one for article: `class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end`

Comment: What you are trying to do is possible, but you should create index and show methods to make it RESTful. Index is for "all", and show is for a single record. See section 2.2.[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use the `Article` as a resource in your route file:

```
resources :articles
```

Doing this you will have to create an `ArticleController` and with the path `/articles` you'll be redirected to a new set of views that will load all the articles without handling the user they come from. Eg. in the `index` action of this controller:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end
```

This is the best way to handle a REST interface in Ruby, since you are querying the `Article` resource alone here, and you should not pass through the `User` resources.